Is a service opening a lot of connections to the database correct?
I have a small application which I have build into a Docker container, run in K8S and read from a PostgresQL database with Npgsql.
I hit it with 10K req / minute on a scale of 4 pods, so in best load balancing should be 2.5k rq / minute / pod.
On each pod I have a connection pool limit of 100, which is nearly full used here. I expected to see 1 connection per pod, because it will share the pool (connection string / database is the same) but in fact I see a spike of 200-250 connections total.
Is that a normal behaviour?

It won't be "1".  If you had only 1, there would be "blocking" on 2-N.    https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/connection-pooling    ..  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/ole-db-odbc-and-oracle-connection-pooling#create-and-assign-pools   not postgres specific, but you can pickup some "in general" how it works at the links.

If you don't keep connections open for long and let NpgSQL use connection pooling (on by default) there won't be a lot of active connections. Once a connection gets closed/disposed, the actual database connection is reset and ready for reuse. If there are no connections in the pool though, new ones will be created. Bad practices, like not using disconnnected operations with ADO.NET, or using fake "repositories" that require explicit transactions on top of EF Core will increase the number of connections and worse, contention in the database. ADO.NET and EF work disconnected by design

If your connection pool limit is 100, it shouldn't be a surprise that it feels free to use a lot of connections.  Your reasoning that it should only use 1 makes no sense to me, but maybe something in the code you haven't shown us would justify that.
